# heartbleed PoC ssltest,py doesn't work, socket.send error : broken pipe

Tags: python, sockets

When I use the following scripts...
http://s3.jspenguin.org/ssltest.py

I get this error:

```
Connecting...
Sending Client Hello...
Waiting for Server Hello...
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 66
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 2924
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 331
 ... received message: type = 22, ver = 0302, length = 4
Sending heartbeat request...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssltepy", line 136, in <module>
    main()
  File "ssltest.py", line 132, in main
    s.send(hb)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

So I wrapped it in a `try` block:

```
try:
    s.send(hb)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

then I got:

```
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssltest.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "ssltest.py", line 136, in main
    hit_hb(s)
  File "ssltest.py", line 84, in hit_hb
    s.send(hb)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I stopped SYMANTEC on my mac, but it didn't work.
I tried "sudo python ssltest.py", but it didn't work.
And I think the code is right.
How to fix the BROKEN PIPE error?

Comment: I'm using Python2